# How to store the parts of Strings in dictionary after splitting it in java

Tags: java, string, dictionary, arraylist, split

I have `split`-ted the strings on ',' for eg frequency:50,current:25,voltage:30 likewise and again from that individual string like frequency:50 again I have `split`-ted on ':' but my question is I want to store that frequency,current,voltage and so on ...all the variables in 0th position in dictionary and 50,25,30 and so on...on 1st position in dictionary and I am going to save the values in database
I have C# code as follow

```
data_dictionary = data.Split(',').ToDictionary(item => item.Split(':')[0], item => item.Split(':')[1]);
```

I want the code to work same like this in java. If dictionary can't work then any other data structure that can work for this please let me know, since I am newbie I am finding it difficult to get the solution.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str = "frequency:50,current:25,voltage:30";

HashMap dict = new HashMap();

for (String s : str.split(",")) {
    dict.put(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add type arguments to the `HashMap`, i.e. `HashMap<String, String>`.